# Stock Journals in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I'm following the [Organize your Deliveries](https://doc.odoo.com/book/5/5_14_Stock/5_14_Stock_journals/) section of the Odoo book. After installing the `sale_journal` it indicates that I should have a stock journals page at `Warehouse ‣ Configuration ‣ Warehouse Management ‣ Stock Journals` but it is missing.  I have the `Invoice Types` page that it mentions.

**Where do I find Stock Journals in Odoo 8?**